# I'm not seeing data I'm writing in Core Data when I dump the SQLite files

Tags: ios

I'm developing for iOS 6.1 and I am learning Core Data.

Things seem to be working reasonably up until I try to write data out.

Some code begin ---

```
next_ID = (NextID *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"NextID" inManagedObjectContext: context];

next_ID.recName = @"Index";

NSLog( @"recName = %@", next_ID.recName );  // <-- looks good

NSError __autoreleasing *err;
BOOL success;

if (!(success = [context save: &err]))
   NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@", err.localizedFailureReason);
else NSLog( @"save DB successful!" );
```

Some code end ---

I get to the 'save DB successful message fine.  But, when I open a terminal window and go to the documents area and do an 'sqlite3 NextID.sqlite .dump', I do not see my "Index" string in the dump.

In fact, what I see in the dump looks the same whether or not I do the next_ID.recName = @"Index"; and save steps.

So, I think it is not updating but I'm baffled as to what to check from here.

Comment: What does your context setup code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what my issue was.  I went and recreated the xcdatamodeid from scratch and very carefully went through it all.  And then it worked.  I write the data and I can now see it in the sqlite3 NextID.sqlite .dump.

Sorry for the bandwidth waste.